# Как выбрать другой метод загрузки в YoutubeDL?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

Если загрузить через youtube_dl видео какого-либо DASH формата (в моём случае 298) сразу:

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
with YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': 'test.mp4', 'format': '298'}) as ydl:
ydl.download(["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXb3EKWsInQ'])
```

, то все 90 Мб загрузятся за пару секунд.

Но если сначала получить прямую ссылку на видео этого же формата и загрузить её:

```
with YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': 'test.mp4'}) as ydl:
  info_dict = ydl.extract_info('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXb3EKWsInQ', download=False)
  url = [i for i in info_dict['formats'] if i['format_id'] == '298'][0]['url']
  ydl.download([url])
```

, то эти же самые 90 Мб будут загружаться несколько минут.

Вот я и думаю, что в первом случае youtube_dl выбрал подходящий способ загрузки для видео, а во втором - не смог. Можно ли как-то самому выбрать нужный метод и загрузить через него?

Comment: Интересно. Если добавить параметр `'verbose': 9` то эти два варианта выдают несколько разные логи. Можно попытаться что-то по исходникам порыть, похоже разобраться будет непросто https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl

Comment: @CrazyElf да, я пытался разобраться в их исходниках, но для меня там сильно всё запутано